# Optimal setup for a simplest URL-route per view/form/report application with React / GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm planning a simple CRUD/reports application with the following characteristics:

- no need to dynamically update a page once its data is loaded for the first time
- separate URL route per page / form / report / whatever (e.g. no need for popup forms which would update the page once submitted)
- no need for optimistic updates
- no need for data caching client side

What I'm trying to achieve here is completely eliminate programming for client to speak to the server. In order to achieve it, I would like use the following stack:

- PostgreSQL with its roles system to manage authentication in the multi-user application
- Postgraphql as a single API endpoint for client to talk to the database
- GraphQL language to fetch all data for a particular URL-route at once before it is rendered
- React Route to manage URL routing in a single-page application

What I'm trying to avoid:

- over-engineering with using Relay for such a simple application by using Relay

The application is more about the quantity of various reports and input forms rather than their complexity.

So the goal here is to compose the forms and reports as quick as possible and declare which data it needs / mutates declaratively, so no any redundant coding is done server-side besides declaring data client-side.

For this application, it is absolutely okay to reload the whole page when:

- a form is submitted
- paging, filtering or ordering changes in a report

Put another way, I'm looking into a way of making a classic PHP-like CRUD application but with using client-side JS only.

I hope it all can be done with using React for easiness of building UI, Redux (do I need it if a page will just reload?), React Route to manage URL routes, and GraphQL as a means to query database from client with no need to use GraphQL's advanced features (fragments, caching, optimistic updates etc).

To make it clear, the most of the business logic is in reports (complex SQL queries), not in the GUI.

I have also looked at code generators, but I'd like not to lock myself into one. I have also seen Postgres Forms project, but it seems as not being actively developed and supported anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to add GraphQL data to your UI in a very simple way, I'd give `apollo-client` and `react-apollo` a try (disclaimer: I'm the main author of this package). You use a React higher order component to attach a query to your component, and it gets fetched and passed to the component via props.

You don't need to set up any build process or tooling to use it, and it doesn't conflict with React Router at all.

The easiest thing is probably to just look at this full-stack example app, which has all of the features you mentioned - simple data fetching and editing: https://github.com/apollostack/GitHunt (Just look in the `ui` folder for some components)

The full documentation is here:

1. How to install/initialize: http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/index.html
2. How to use with React: http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/react.html#connect

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. Should it work with Redux seamlessly?

Comment: Yep - that's one of the main goals, you can attach your graphql data to the redux store, track queries and mutations via the redux dev tools, and use redux state in your query and mutation variables.

Comment: sorry to piggy back on this post, but I am more confused about apollo now. I thought graphQL was an alternative to Redux, you are saying with apollo it works with Redux. How? I have a php api that makes all of my db calls. They are dumped into Redux with reducers. This works well, but I read GraphQL can make one call to the db for all of my connections. I am not seeing the landscape of apollo. I guess I need to read up more.